# Prerequisites for Exposing a WCF REST Service to the Internet Hosted in Windows Service

Tags: wcf, rest, hosting

What are the prerequisites (or steps) to host a WCF REST based service on internet. I have made the application and is working fine on local and intranet. But i want to know what all is needed for hosting the same on a server (like open the port,etc) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that your server is accessible externally, so you must have a public IP/Domain name that can be resolved by DNS server. If your network/server has Firewall, then you need to make sure that you configure it to allow connection on that port. Same for Router, you will need to allow for the traffic to pass through. For example if you are using

```
net.tcp://www.mywcfsite.com:6000/service.svc
```

then you will need to make sure the network is open for tcp protocol and port 6000.

Exactly the same will apply for http traffic.